# No response on live transition request

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using YouTube Live Streaming API in java.
and I have a problem that some times occurs.

I wrote a class that retrieves an existing Live Stream and creates a Live Broadcast, makes sure that that Stream is sending data , then it binds them together,  then i make 2 transition requests.

first i make transition to Testing (live preview) request , then I make transition to  Live request ,
the manual on https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast section 4.1 says
I should poll the API until the broadcast life cycle status changes to live

here is what i wrote:
'''

```
 YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Transition requestLive = CreateYouTube.getYoutube().liveBroadcasts()
                    .transition("live", returnedBroadcast.getId(), "snippet,status");
            returnedBroadcast = requestLive.execute();
            //poll while live starting (wait while starting live)
  while(returnedBroadcast.getStatus().getLifeCycleStatus().equals("liveStarting")) {
           returnedBroadcast = getBroadcastById(returnedBroadcast.getId());
           System.out.println("polling liveStarting "+args[0]);
           Thread.sleep(1000);
 }
```

'''
sometimes it works smoothly , but on other time the status doesn't change , that means the broadcast doesn't  transition to live , and I get stuck in an infinite loop.
of course i can break out of the loop manually , but I still don't understand why the request isn't handled and can i fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem that was causing the live broadcast not to start at times. 
The problem was that the output resolution of the encoding  software 
did not match the resolution that was set to the live stream "cdn" settings when creating the stream.

The YouTube Live API didn't manage to throw an exception or to notify my program and just went to an infinite loop in the code i posted above,
I found this problem when i was in the new beta version of Live Control Room which notified me that the encoder output resolution doesn't match the stream resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking for the state `liveStarting` instead of `live`? The timeout could be getting *unlucky* and missing the state completely. `liveStarting` is a transitional state.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#status.lifeCycleStatus

I also recommend looking at the `contentDetails.enableAutoStart` property on the `LiveBroadcast` resource.

You can update the `LiveBroadcast` to `enableAutoStart: true` before attaching the `LiveStream`. I found this a much more reliable way of getting streams to start.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#contentDetails.enableAutoStart

Comment: thanks for the tips , i found the problem you can read my answer above